# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-image, flutter-image-picker

I am getting error as described in image. You can check error with line.
Actually, I am trying to add two options in `modalBottomSheet`. the first is Camera and second is Gallery. Then if gallery is selected so, I want to navigate to the `StatusImage()` page where I am passing argument of selected file. So, when I select image then it is not navigating to the `StatusImage()` and showing error which is in terminal inside image.

[image]

This is `takePhoto()` method.

```
Future<PickedFile?> takePhoto(ImageSource source) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: source);

    return pickedFile;
  }
```

This code is inside onTap:

```
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        PickedFile? imageFile =
                            await takePhoto(ImageSource.gallery);
                        setState(() {
                          imageFile != null
                              ? Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => StatusImage(
                                            name: userName,
                                            userId: currentUserId,
                                            imageFile: File(imageFile.path),
                                          )))
                              : Container();
                          imageFile;
                        });
```

Let me know where is problem exactly.

Comment: I'm afraid you shouldn't ignore `use_build_context_synchronously` (https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html)...

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just removed it.